# Prove or Disprove Compactness

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, continuity, compactness

Prove or Disprove: Suppose that $f$ is a real-valued function that is continuous on a nonempty set $S$ in $\mathbb{R}^n$ and that $f(S)$ is compact in $\mathbb{R}$. Then $S$ is a compact set $\mathbb{R}^n$.

I just studied the concept of compactness and I am stuck trying to prove/disprove the above statement. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Suppose $f(x) = 1$, so that $f(S) = \{1\}$ for any set $S$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $f : \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be a continuous function which is $1$ if $x$ is in $(-1,1)$, $0$ outside of $[-2,2]$, and between $0$ and $1$ on the intervals $[-2,-1]$ and $[1,2]$. Then $f((-1/2,1/2)) = \{1\}$ but $(-1/2,1/2)$ is not compact.

It helps if your map is proper: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proper_map